# Python Simple Salesforce and salesforce rest authentication errors

Tags: rest-api, simple-salesforce

An absolute python newbie & trying to establish a connection between python & salesforce.
Followed this documentation - https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/ and we have a python script that has a payload similar to the one mentioned in the above link.

Here is a sample of my payload with result --

```
payload = {
  "firstname": "test",
"lastname" : "name",
"email":"test@test.com"
}

result = sf.apexecute('/applications', method='POST', data=payload)

print(result)
```

where `/applications` is the end point url in the apex rest service.

I am able to establish the connection with UN, PW, Instance url & Token but I get the below error when I run my python run.py

```
 /simple_salesforce/util.py", line 61, in exception_handler
    raise exc_cls(result.url, result.status_code, name, response_content)
**simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceResourceNotFound: Resource apexexcute Not Found. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'NOT_FOUND', 'message': 'The requested resource does not exist'}]**
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an authentication error. You are calling the wrong method on your `simple_salesforce` connection object. I believe you're receiving that specific error message due to how `simple_salesforce` translates Python method calls into REST endpoints.

The `apexecute` method is for calling custom Apex REST endpoints. From the `simple_salesforce` documentation:

```
result = sf.apexecute('User/Activity', method='POST', data=payload)
```

> This would call the endpoint https://.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/User/Activity with data= as the body content encoded with json.dumps

Your error message suggests you've spelled this wrong, as `apexexcute`. Make sure to call the method as documented, and include the portion of your REST service's URL after `/apexrest/` only in the first parameter.

Note that with `simple_salesforce`, you create sObject records like this:

```
sf.Contact.create({'LastName':'Smith','Email':'example@example.com'})
```

replacing `Contact` with the API name of the sObject you want to create. If that is your use case, it's not necessary to go all the way to an Apex REST service.